# Datatable view is not in style/standard format

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to figure out what I've missed during my coding on my project. My problem is my datatable format/style is not what it seems to look like from standard format. I'm using ASP.net MVC.

This is the output: **Page numbers, search box is not in style**

[Page numbers, search box is not in style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy9vA.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
  

    <div class="col-sm-20c">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table id="tbl-transaction" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Transaction No</th>
                        <th>Purpose of Visit</th>
                        <th>Name of Host</th>
                        <th>Transacted By</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

@section Scripts

{

   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>



    <script>

       getall();

       function getall()
       {
           
           $('#tbl-transaction').dataTable().fnDestroy();
           $('#tbl-transaction').DataTable({

               "ajax": {

                   "url": '/FSEWeb/Admin/GetAllTransactions',
                   "type": "get",
                   "datatype" : "JSON"

               },

               "columns" :
                   [

                       { data :"TransactionNumber"},
                       { data: "PurposeOfVisit" },
                       { data: "NameOfHostFromST" },
                       { data: "TransactedBy" },
                        {
                            data: null, "render" : function(data,type,row)
                            {
                                return '<button class= "btn btn-success" onclick = "get_details(' + data.id + ',' + data.TransactionNumber + ')"> Details </button>';
                            }
                        }
                   ]

           })

       }
```

This table format is what I want to look like.

[Desired output with styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8mQs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have not incorporated JQuery Datatbles style sheet i.e.

```
<!-- Data table -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css " />
```

Incorporate it at layout level or page level.